# преобразовать массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Массив

```
[
    {"name":"root", "parentId":null, "id":100},
    {"name":"1stlevelChild1", "parentId":100, "id":201},
    {"name":"1stlevelChild2", "parentId":100, "id":202},
    {"name":"2ndlevelChild1", "parentId":201, "id":301},
    {"name":"2ndlevelChild2", "parentId":201, "id":301}
]
```

Преобразовать в иерархический

```
[
 {
   "name":"root", 
   "parentId":null, 
   "id":100, 
   "childs":[
        {
            "name":"1stlevelChild1", 
            "parentId":100, 
            "id":201, 
            "childs":[
                {"name":"2ndlevelChild1", "parentId":201, "id":301, "childs":[]},
                {"name":"2ndlevelChild2", "parentId":201, "id":301, "childs":[]}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"1stlevelChild2", 
            "parentId":100, 
            "id":202,
            "childs":[]
        }
   ]
 }
]
```

Какими способами это можно сделать, какие функции использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var input = [
    {"name":"root", "parentId":null, "id":100},
    {"name":"1stlevelChild1", "parentId":100, "id":201},
    {"name":"1stlevelChild2", "parentId":100, "id":202},
    {"name":"2ndlevelChild1", "parentId":201, "id":301},
    {"name":"2ndlevelChild2", "parentId":201, "id":302}
];

var output = [];
var lookup = {};

// prepare lookup container and arrays for children 
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].children = [];
  lookup[input[i].id] = input[i];
}

// distribute items from input to output and their parents
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (input[i].parentId == null)
    output.push(input[i]);
  else
    lookup[input[i].parentId].children.push(input[i]);
}

console.log(output);
```

Объекты во входном массиве не имеют массивов для детей, создаем их в цикле в каждом объекте: `input[i].children = [];`. Чтобы быстро находить родителя по его `id`, используем bracket notation обращения к свойствам js объектов, а в качестве названий свойств - значения `id` элементов массива: `lookup[input[i].id] = input[i];`. Когда нам понадобится быстро найти родительский объект, мы найдем его в `lookup`, как свойство `lookup[input[i].parentId]`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, только один вопрос: что оно за ошибки выдает?
{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}
{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}
И так несколько раз

Comment: @Alexey Нажмите, пожалуйста, на кнопку "Выполнить код" внизу моего ответа. Есть ошибки? Какие?

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: Я открыл эту страницу в Chrome, Firefox, Edge и IE11. Нигде ошибок нет. Какой у Вас браузер?

Comment: Chrome. Сразу после выполнения кода ниже появляются ошибки. А вот в Edge такого нет)

Comment: Мы говорим вот об этой странице, на которой мы сейчас находимся?

Comment: Именно, могу приложить скриншот

Comment: Давайте,  даже интересно.

Comment: http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/02/5245e36813cd09494fcd9a4b38f8e188.jpg
ошибки сразу после выполнения кода

Comment: хм, это явно ошибки не кода в ответе, последняя строчка `console.log(output);` отработала нормально.

Comment: Согласен, спасибо!
Можно еще пару вопросов по коду?
Зачем нужен lookup?
и что делают эти строчки?
input[i].children = [];
  lookup[input[i].id] = input[i];

Comment: Объекты во входном массиве не имеют массивов для детей, создаем их в цикле в каждом объекте: `input[i].children = [];`. Чтобы быстро находить родителя по его `id`, используем bracket notation обращения к свойствам js объектов, а в качестве названий свойств - значения `id` элементов массива: `lookup[input[i].id] = input[i];`. Когда нам понадобится быстро найти родительский объект, мы найдем его в `lookup`, как свойство `lookup[input[i].parentId]`. - добавлю-ка я это в ответ

Comment: Теперь все понятно, спасибо огромное!